# Comparing two arrays..in c

Tags: c

I set up two arrays one of 50 units big, array1[50] which has 50 random integers from a range of 50-100 and another array which prompts the user to enter in 10 intgers from the same range of numbers. My problem is, how do i compare the two, im tyring to find the number of times the 10 user inputted numbers match the numbers stored in the array1[50] which holds the seedeed random numbers. Ive tried to do a for loop within a for loop, like this.

```
array2[10]
array[50]
int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    for(int k = 0; k < 50; ++k){  //i've tried this and it does not work, i don't know what else to do
        if( array2[i] == array[k]);
        ++counter;
    }
}
//any help is appreciated thanks.
```

Comment: I doubt you want the semicolon at the end here, `if( array2[i] == array[k]);`. That turns the `if` into a noop and `++counter` executes unconditionally.

Comment: Please remove the `;` after `if( array2[i] == array[k]);`. Depending on what you are actually counting, you may want to `break` from the inner loop when a match is found.

Comment: You'll be wanting an array of 10 counters.

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways to achieve this using other libraries. But considering you're working with small arrays, you could use your code with the following modification:

```
array2[10]
array[50]
int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
for(int k = 0; k < 50; ++k){  
if( array2[i] == array[k])counter++;
}
}
```

That should work.